# Responsive CSS square

Tags: css, responsive-design

Using just CSS and not javascript, how would I make a square based on the minimum of the window's width/height?

I've seen various approaches, but I want it to be responsive whether you're on a typical laptop or a mobile device.

JQuery can do this using `Math.min($(window).width(), $(window).height())` but there's got to be a way to accomplish this via CSS no?

Comment: if you want both width and height to always be the same, you will need javascript

Answer (score 0):

Without text in the div, you can do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

div {width: 20%; padding-bottom: 20%; background: #F97E76;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

It's useful if, say, you are creating a gallery, as you can apply background images to the boxes. It's not much use as a layout tool for text containers, though.

You could put some text in it like this (although it will quickly overflow at small sizes):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.outer {width: 20%; padding-bottom: 20%; background: #F97E76; position: relative;}
.inner {position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; right: 10px; bottom: 10px;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <p>This is text within the div, lots of text that's pretty useless.</p>
        <p>This is text within the div, lots of text that's pretty useless.</p>
        <p>This is text within the div, lots of text that's pretty useless.</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out using CSS3's media queries and **vh**/**vw** units (viewport), you can do it case by case:

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait) {     
    #itemToCenter {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vw;
    }  
}
@media all and (orientation:landscape) {
    #itemToCenter {
        width: 100vh;
        height: 100vh;      
    }   
}
```